Why are the radially objects not directly from center using?

When I increase the radius the object translate away but from the center at an offset.

The origin of the instances must be aligned to what you expect to be the axis. Either you got misplaced origins or the translation in X only is affecting this. If the origin is aligned, the translation in X and Y should use cos(60º) and sin(60º) respectively. (ALternatively, you rotate the original geometry 30º so X crosses exactly in the middle of the arc)

Thanks. And yes that was the issue. I rotated the previous node on X -60 and viola. the alignment was great.
